# Redirection in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 - and want to do this:

`/someword` `->` redirects to `controller=>someword` and `action=>index`
`/someword/otherword` `->` redirects to `controller=>someword`, `action=>view` and `param=>otherword`.

I tried doing a `Router::connect` with '`/someword/*`' (hoping that it would try and match something after the last `/`). This doesn't work.

Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured it out. It was super simple.

```
Router::connect('/someword/:slug', array('controller'=>'someword', 'action'=>'view'), array('pass'=>array('slug')));
```